# Cannot initialize type 'class' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'IEnumerable'

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

can anyone tell me why this doesnt work?

```
 public class GeocodeCoord
 {
     public string Outcode { get; set; }
     public int X { get; set; }
     public int Y { get; set; }
 }
```

---

```
List<GeocodeCoord> _geocode;

using (MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext())
{
   _geocode = db.Geocodes.Select(g => new GeocodeCoord { g.postcode, g.x, g.y }).ToList<GeocodeCoord>();
}
```

I get the following error:

Cannot initialize type 'Search.GeocodeCoord' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: What does not work? Do you get an exception? Do you get a compile time error?

Comment: I get a compiler error, just added extra info.. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line should be:

```
_geocode = db.Geocodes.Select(g => new GeocodeCoord { Outcode = g.postcode, X = g.x, Y = g.y }).ToList();
```

Comment: Beautiful!! Thanks you very much :).. Just tried it and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ToList()`, the compiler will find the correct type for you.

Comment: If I do this  _geocode = db.Geocodes.Select(g => new GeocodeCoord { g.postcode, g.x, g.y }).ToList(); I get the same error.
If i do the following: 
_geocode = db.Geocodes.Select(g => new { g.postcode, g.x, g.y }).ToList(); 
I get Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Search.GeocodeCoord>'

Answer (score 0):

Type in the property names of the initializer like `new GeocodeCoord { Postcode = g.postcode, X = g.x, Y = g.y }`